# Subtracting multiple values inside a column from each other by conditional pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I am struggling with something that I think should be very trivial.

I have an input dataframe as:

| id | months | feature_a | feature_b | feature_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 4 |

Now I want to group by id and subtract for each feature the value where the month is 6 by where the month is 1. Resulting in an output dataframe as:

| id | feature_a | feature_b | feature_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Now I am managing to do this with the following code:

```
def get_month_diff(df, start_month=1, end_month=6):

    columns_to_agg = ['feature_a', 'feature_b', 'feature_c']
    result = (df
               .groupby('id')
               .pivot('months')
               .agg(*[F.sum(col).alias(f'{col}') for col in columns_to_agg])
               )
    #  Pyspark doesnt work nice with columns that have '.'s in them
    result = result.toDF(*(c.replace('.', '_') for c in result.columns))

    for col in columns_to_agg:
        result = result.withColumn(col, result[f"{end_month}_0_{col}"] - result[f"{start_month}_0_{col}"])

    return result
```

I don't like that I have to do the substracting of one column from another column and creating these new columns outside the first spark transformation. So I am looking for a solution.

Therefore I am asking if someone could help me in the right direction for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid a pivot if you use `max` with `when` to get the values for month 1 and 6:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('id').agg(*[
    (
        F.max(F.when(F.col('months') == 6, F.col(c))) - 
        F.max(F.when(F.col('months') == 1, F.col(c)))
    ).alias(c) 
    for c in df.columns[2:]
])

df2.show()
+---+---------+---------+---------+
| id|feature_a|feature_b|feature_c|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|        1|        1|        1|
|  2|        1|        1|        1|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Aah really cool thank you :D. One question if I may ask. Why is the F.max necessary here? I notice that it does not work without. But intuitively why do we need a max function?

Comment: If there are multiple rows with months = 1, one value has to be chosen. Of course it doesn't happen in your case, but Spark doesn't know how your data looks like.